# Full break out javascript from child function

Tags: javascript

Simple question, I guess...

```
function foo1() {
    foo2();
    // should not hit this line
}
function foo2() {
    foo3();
    // should not hit this line
}
function foo3() {
   if(someCondition)
      // should not hit this line
}
```

if in foo3(), if I use simple return, it will continue execution in foo2() and foo3().

I understand it is possible tocheck for return value and so on, I am just wondering if it is possible to exit completely from foo3()?

Comment: This is pure javascript I don't see any `angularJs` code

Comment: Only way to exit a function is to return.

Comment: @Merlin, yes, added angular tag by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually answer your question, sure, you could [`throw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) from `foo3()`:

```js
function foo1() {
  console.log(1)
  foo2()
  console.log("Never hits")
}

function foo2() {
  console.log(2)
  foo3(3)
  console.log("Never hits")
}

function foo3() {
  if (true)
    throw "Breakout"
}

try {
  foo1()
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

This is part of the reason exceptions bubble. There may be reasons for aborting an execution in this manner, but you may wish to consider alternatives.

<strike>But you *probably* don't want to do that as this is a very smelly architecture, but you already know the more idiomatic alternative is to check returns.</strike>

Comment: Thank you, true ))

Comment: @monstro No problem, I recently saw an interesting talk about this (in Scala) and it convinced me that always treating errors as values -- as in checking `return`s later on -- is not _universally_ the best option.